# Is there any way to disable mouse click on a RichTextBox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, richtextbox, disabled-input

I'm using a visible RitchTextBox to write an automatic log and I don't want that the user change the cursor position. I can't just disable the control because it loses its background color (when the log is full it's saved as RTF file).
I've already set `ReadOnly = True` and `ShorcutsEnabled = False`.

My code:

```
Protected Friend Sub PrintPort(ByVal NewText As String, Optional ByVal ForeColor As Color = Nothing, Optional ByVal NewLine As Boolean = True)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim Txt As New PrintSmsLogDelegate(AddressOf PrintPort)
        Me.BeginInvoke(Txt, NewText, ForeColor, NewLine)
    Else
        If ClearLogFl Then
            ClearLogFl = False
            Me.RTB1.Clear()
        End If

        If NewText.Length < 1 Then
            Return
        End If

        If ForeColor = Nothing Then
            ForeColor = Color.White
        End If

        If NewLine Then
            If Me.RTB1.TextLength > 1 Then
                NewText = vbCrLf + NewText
            End If
        End If

        Me.RTB1.SelectionColor = ForeColor 'Set color
        Me.RTB1.SelectedText = NewText 'Add text

        If Me.LogAutoScrollChk.Checked And NewText.Contains(vbLf) Then
            Me.RTB1.ScrollToCaret()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try setting Focusable, IsTabStop, and IsHitTestVisible all to False

Comment: Set it `ReadOnly` and in its `Enter` event add: `this.ActiveControl = null;`. The User can still move the ScrollBars, if any (of course, the RTB cannot be the AcitveControl when the Form is first shown, otherwise it will receive back the input focus, making this all quite weird).

Comment: Sure. I meant `Me.ActiveControl = Nothing`.

Comment: @schulmaster is VB.2010 and I can't see those properties.

Comment: @Jimi The text still gets corrupted after I click inside the older text. I added the code that I'm using to the original question; maybe you understand better whats happening. Thanks

Comment: This is because of the overly-complicated Color selection method. You need to set `RTB1.SelectionStart = RTB1.TextLength` before `RTB1.SelectionColor = Color.SomeColor`, then `RTB1.AppendText("Some text" & VbLf) RTB1.SelectionColor = RTB1.ForeColor`. Your Invoking procedure is also overly-complicated: you don't need a delegate when you call `BeginInvoke()`, since there's no risk involved in invoking from the same Thread. Just `BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub()  'stuff End Sub))`

Comment: @Jimi LMAO! That is what I was doing in other projects; I just used this method in this particular project because it looks easier to understand. I mean, there's no need to calculate the color selection length.

Comment: No, there's no need. Just set `SelectionStart` and `SelectionColor`. After that, new Text is rendered using the Color selected. You can reset it to default, if necessary. Or not. In your case (no User interaction), it's not even required.

Comment: Perhaps a better idea rather than writing your log directly to richtextbox, write it to a string list behind the scenes that you have full control over, then use your richtextbox to display your string collection, although I would go with  something like a list box which might be better suited

Answer (score 2):

An example, using a Threaded Timer (`System.Timers.Timer`) to **simulate** a method called from a Thread other than the UI Thread.

The RichTexBox Control needs to *refuse* User interaction: neither the text or the caret position can be modified and the User cannot *interfere* with the scrolling procedure, activated or not.

- We can set the RichTextBox as `ReadOnly` and remove the Scrollbars (neither of these are actually required, but it's a better option, IMO).
- In the `Enter` event of the RicheTextBox, the [Form.ActiveControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol) is set to `null` (`Nothing`), so the RichTextBox is not the `ActiveControl` anymore, thus it doesn't receive the Keyboard or Mouse Input.
  Note that with this setup, there's no chance to directly interact with the RTB, even if it's the only Control in the Form that can receive the Focus.
- Since your `PrintPort()` method is apparently called from another Thread, you need to Invoke the UI Thread to append to the Control.
  [BeginInvoke()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) can simplify the invocation procedure, using a Lambda as the Action delegate.
  There's no need to check `InvokeRequired`, `BeginInvoke()` can be safely called also from the same Thread where the invocation is performed (the UI Thread).

```
Private Shared rndColor As New Random()
Private threadedTimer As System.Timers.Timer = Nothing

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    rtb1.ReadOnly = True
    rtb1.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None
    AddHandler rtb1.Enter, Sub() ActiveControl = Nothing

    threadedTimer = New System.Timers.Timer() With {.Interval = 1000}
    AddHandler threadedTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf TimerElapsedHandler
    threadedTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub TimerElapsedHandler(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
    BeginInvoke(New Action(
        Sub()
            If Not rtb1.IsHandleCreated Then Return
            Dim rndValue = rndColor.Next(2)
            rtb1.SelectionStart = rtb1.TextLength
            rtb1.SelectionColor = If(rndValue = 1, Color.Orange, Color.YellowGreen)
            rtb1.AppendText(If(rndValue = 1, "Some other Text", "Some new text") & VbLf)
            If LogAutoScrollChk.Checked Then rtb1.ScrollToCaret()
        End Sub)
    )
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(e As FormClosingEventArgs)
    threadedTimer.Stop()
    RemoveHandler threadedTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf TimerElapsedHandler
    threadedTimer.Dispose()
    MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
End Sub
```

---

[image: ReadOnly RichTextBox BeginInvoke]

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own RichTextBox for this.  I converted the c# answer in [make richtextbox not respond to mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36147414/719186) and added the handling of the Paging keys:

```
Public Class DisplayBox
  Inherits RichTextBox

  Private Const WM_SETFOCUS As Integer = &H7
  Private Const WM_ENABLE As Integer = &HA
  Private Const WM_SETCURSOR As Integer = &H20

  Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If Not (m.Msg = WM_SETFOCUS OrElse m.Msg = WM_ENABLE OrElse m.Msg = WM_SETCURSOR) Then
      MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End If
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyDown(e As KeyEventArgs)
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.PageDown Or e.KeyCode = Keys.PageUp) Then
      e.Handled = True
    End If
    MyBase.OnKeyDown(e)
  End Sub

End Class
```

Works when the `ReadOnly = True` and `ScrollBars = None` properties are set.